# Custom task in Sharepoint Designer 2010

Tags: 2010, workflow, custom, designer

I have a custom task to send an Email task in SharePoint 2010. When the user gets the email and hits, "Open this task" the Complete Task box pops up with that button. I need the box to pop with Approve or Deny to come up. Any advice on how to set that workflow up?

Answer (score 0):

Workflow Task Forms can be used to change the interaction between the user and the workflow. I included a couple links that you can use to create either a Visual Studio workflow form or use SharePoint designer to customize a workflow form.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms438856.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms497641.aspx

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/introduction-to-designing-and-customizing-workflows-HA101859249.aspx#_Toc261009032